# My css class code doesnt works, it should at be the bottom but it's now working

Tags: php, html, css

Php code 
i searched on the web and i didnt see anything about this it looks like no error css status is 200
css code is at the **bottom**.

```css
.sagalt {
  margin-top: 500px
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>quantum</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo.png" type="image/png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="qntm.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
  <!--link//-->
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <a href="logout.php" class="sagalt">Sign Out</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where is the php? what is the issue you are having exactly?

Comment: Document is php and css doesnt works in it.

Answer (score 1):

Think you are trying to apply CSS to the link. Anchor tag being an inline element, margin top/bottom property alone wont have an effect in it as inline elements flow with content on the page. Use display: inline-block or display: flex or float: left as per your requirement.

```css
.sagalt {
  color: red;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>quantum</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo.png" type="image/png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="qntm.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
  <!--link//-->
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <a href="logout.php" class="sagalt">Sign Out</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```